# PrestaShop: hide/show payment method if VAT exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I want to hide a payment method and show it only if customer has enterd a VAT number. 
I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="vat_number"/>
<a class="universalpay" title="Invoice">INVOICE PAYMENT</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[title='Invoice']").hide();

    $('#vat_number').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $("a[title='Invoice']").show();
        }
        else
        {
           $("a[title='Invoice']").hide();      
        }
    })
});
```

But problem is that when someone press "Accept the terms & condition" it reloads the payment methods and then it shows agian.

How can i force it to hide until the VAT is filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ajaxComplete` method:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // Check if we are in order page
    if($('body').attr('id') == 'order'){
         if($('#vat_number').val().length != 0){
             $("a[title='Invoice']").show();
         } else {
             $("a[title='Invoice']").hide();
         }

    }
});
```

Comment: Your code works perfect! Just add  $("a[title='Invoice']").hide(); befoce the if, so that it hides from start.

Comment: This snippet is an addition to your `$(document).ready()`, there you hide from start :)